# LINQ to get two integers in an array whose sum is closest to zero

Tags: c#, linq

Given an array of integers (with +ve and -ve numbers which are unordered), 
what is the LINQ statement to find those two numbers whose sum is closest to 0

E.g `int[] a = new int[]{2, 56, -11, 15, 12, 10, 43, -59, -13}`

In the above set of integers {`-11`,`10`} and {`12`,`-13`} are the two set of two integers which is closest to `0`

I could not get much, except the following basic query of LINQ as i was not sure how to proceed,

```
var res =    from x in a
             WHERE //i am stuck in the logic what to write here
             select x
```

Comment: Is this homework? Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: IMO you have to make 2 arrays `arr1 = input.Where(i => i < 0); arr2 = input.Where(i => i => 0);` and then check every possible combination. But this can take ages with huge tables.

Comment: @m.rogalski it is not efficient enough  he can have two elements with values 1 and the sum of 2 will be closest in a lot of cases.

Comment: Why should `-1` be closest to `0` than `1` given by {`-11`, `12`} ? Also, why Linq ?

Comment: I'll give you a hint, you don't need a `where` you need to create the set of all pairs and then order them on the absolute value of the sum.

Comment: @Sehnsucht: `-1` and `1` both hold good as answer. why Linq: i am writting this logic in C#, so am opting for LINQ or Lambda expression

Comment: I have jotted down a small sample to see if its useful for the user. Can the question be reopened?

Comment: @hypnos: could you please mention the sample you tried in the comment section for now. or you can mail me at ismailece2007@gmail.com

Comment: @ismail: try loooking at this.
            int[] numbers = { 2, 56, -11, 15, 12, 10, 43, -59, -13 };

            var res = (from pos in numbers
                      where pos >= 0
                      from neg in numbers
                      where neg < 0
                      select new[] { pos, neg,  pos + neg })
                      .OrderBy( x => x.GetValue(2));

            foreach (var i in res)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", i.GetValue(0), i.GetValue(1), i.GetValue(2));

            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: @ismailbaig: i've a second try to select only those results which differs from a zero by a given range

Comment: the sum of any two integers from the set or should they be neighboors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be any two values in the set then you can do this...

```
var set = new int[] { 2, 56, -11, 15, 12, 10, 43, -59, -13 };

var ret = (from a in set
           from b in set
           orderby Math.Abs(a + b)
           select new
           {
               a,
               b
           }).First();

Console.WriteLine(ret); // {a: -11, b:12 }
```

If you want slightly better performance for large sets (and can assume there are negative and positive values mixed) you can do this.

```
var set = new int[] { 2, 56, -11, 15, 12, 10, 43, -59, -13 };

var ret = (from a in set.Where(x => x >= 0)
           from b in set.Where(y => y < 0)
           orderby Math.Abs(a + b)
           select new
           {
               a,
               b
           }).First();

Console.WriteLine(ret); // { a= 12, b= -11}
```

And since you now want the entire set of matches excluding matching to one's self...

```
var set = new int[] { 2, 56, -11, 15, 12, 10, 43, -59, -13 };

var ret = from a in set
          from b in set
          where a != b
          let c = new { a, b }
          group c by Math.Abs(c.a + c.b);

var minset = ret.First(i => i.Key == ret.Min(j => j.Key))
                .Select(s=>s);

Console.WriteLine(minset.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
                                   (sb,v)=>sb.Append(v)
                                             .AppendLine()
                                  ));

/*
    { a = -11, b = 12 }
    { a = -11, b = 10 }
    { a = 12, b = -11 }
    { a = 12, b = -13 }
    { a = 10, b = -11 }
    { a = -13, b = 12 }
*/
```

And to dedup....

```
var set = new[] { 2, 56, -11, 15, 12, 10, 43, -59, -13 };

var ret = from a in set
            from b in set
            where a != b
            let c = new { a, b }
            group c by Math.Abs(c.a + c.b);

var minset = ret.First(i => i.Key == ret.Min(j => j.Key))
                .Select(s => new { a = Math.Min(s.a, s.b), b = Math.Max(s.a, s.b) })
                .Distinct();

Console.WriteLine(minset.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
                                    (sb, v) => sb.Append(v)
                                                .AppendLine()));

/*
    { a = -11, b = 12 }
    { a = -11, b = 10 }
    { a = -13, b = 12 }
*/
```

Comment: +1 for the logic, but this logic gives only the first set and not all the sets whose sum is near to zero.

Comment: The above logic may fail if we have only one 0 in the array as it tries to add 0 of set a and 0 of set b.

Comment: You said you wanted the one closest pair if you want the set change to a group by the filter for the minimum.

Comment: yes i agree with if i wanted only one (any) set, the above logic works fine and group by filter will give me all the sets closest, but the issue in second comment will still persist (if am right even after group by).

Comment: and if you used the middle answer with the group by the 0+0 would also never happen but again it has the assumption that you have both positive and negative numbers.  (though it is possible for the difference between two numbers (positive and negative) to be larger than the sum of two positive whole numbers.  (ie: 1 + -59 v. 1 + 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = new [] { 2, 56, -11, 15, 12, 10, 43, -59, -13 };

// TODO : assert data.Length >= 2
var query = from i in Enumerable.Range (0, data.Length - 2)
            from j in Enumerable.Range (i + 1, data.Length - 1 - i)
            let x = data[i] let y = data[j]
            group new { x, y } by Math.Abs (x + y) into g
            orderby g.Key select g;

Console.WriteLine (string.Join ("\n", query.First ()));
```

> { x = -11, y = 12 }
>   { x = -11, y = 10 }
>   { x = 12, y = -13 }